# Range Object Mozilla Firefox startOffset not working correctly

Tags: javascript, object, firefox, range

I am building an Editor with the Range Object from Mozilla and Internet Explorer...

The thing is the following:

I have an Text in an div Box and now I select this text and get the start and offset with the Range Object -> with `startOffset` and `endOffset`.

In IE it works fine but in the Firefox I have the Problem, that repeated Text is not working correctly - it always takes only the first Text and is ignoring the other text range ...

So here my code:

```
function get_start() {

    var markiert = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

    alert(markiert.startOffset);

}

function get_ende() {

    var markiert = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

    alert(markiert.endOffset);

}
```

And it will display the start- and end-point of the selected string.

Comment: Do you have a complete testcase? I'm having trouble to understand what's the "repeated Text" that "is not working correctly"? Anyway, the `Range` object is quite complicated to use properly: are you sure the selection you have is inside a single `Node` (i.e. range.startContainer === range.endContainer?)

Comment: okay i.e. the Text is "HALLOHALLO" and i want to get now the start and end point of the text is mozilla it have problems with the repeated word...

Comment: Still without testcase it's hard to tell. It's highly unlikely that the specific letters in the Text node affect selection (does it work with "HALLOWORLD" for example?), what likely matters is how you got that node in the first place.

Comment: Hi everyone, now i found rangy (https://github.com/timdown/rangy) its pretty cool to handle Selections with JavaScript ;)